# Can we get a home loan on a house which is registered in my parents names?

Tags: mortgage, india, banking, home-loan

Can we get home loan which is registered in my (deceased) parents' names?

On the registration papers my name and my sister, brothers name are also there. Can we get a home loan?

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Can you edit and add more details? Have you removed the parents from the registration? Have you spoken to a bank? There are 'votes to close' this as unclear, but you can edit to help us understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

Home loan... No.

You can, however, get a loan against the property. First, you will have remove your parents' names and get the home re-registered in your name.

You and your siblings will then have to apply together for the loan against the property.